# Update UISearchBar manually after rotation

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've got a UISearchDisplayController with a UISearchBar. After rotation the SearchBar isn't set up correctly anymore. It's a bit wider than the screen. When I drag the TableView just a bit, the searchbar adjusts it's frame and fits on top of the tableview the way it should.

Is there a way to manually "re-setup" oder "reposition" the searchbar by reloading something?

Thanks a lot!
Sebastian